# Integral with exponential Brownian motion

Tags: integration, brownian-motion, finance

I was working through the pricing of some binary option and after changing measure and doing some clean up, I have arrived at the following quantity:

$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}\left[ \exp(cW_T) \cdot 1\{\sup_{t \leq T} W_t \geq a\}\right]$$

Where above $W_t$ is $\mathbb{P}$-brownian motion, and $a, c$ and $T$ are fixed constants.

I was attempting it as follows: Let $\tau_a$ denote the first time $W_t$ reaches $a$. Then, we know the density for $f_{\tau_a}(t)$:

$$f_{\tau_a}(t) = \frac{a \exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{2t}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}$$

Then:

$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}\left[ \exp(cW_T) \cdot 1\{\sup_{t \leq T} W_t \geq a\}\right] = \int_0^T \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}\left[\exp(cW_T)|W_t = a\right] f_{\tau_a}(t) dt $$

we also have:

$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}\left[\exp(cW_T)|W_t = a\right] = \exp(ca + c^2(T-t) / 2)$$

to get the above we can use the strong markov property and the reflection property.

Putting everything together:

$$I:=\int_0^T \frac{\exp\left(ca + \frac{c^2 (T-t)}{2} - \frac{a^2}{2t} \right)}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}dt $$

At this point I started reading some material and I saw that my desired quantity was equal to

\begin{align} J:=e^{ca} \int_0^\infty \left( e^{cx} + e^{-cx}\right) e^{-(x+a)^2 /(2T)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi T}}dx
\end{align}

This integral is much easier to do by hand and we get:

$$ J = e^{ca} \left( \exp\left(\frac{c^2 T - 2ac}{2}\right) \Phi\left(\frac{cT - a}{\sqrt{T}}\right) + \exp\left(\frac{c^2 T + 2ac}{2}\right) \Phi\left(\frac{-cT - a}{\sqrt{T}}\right) \right)$$

where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF for the standard normal distribution.

I have checked (doing numeric integration with a few different set of values) that the integrals in $J$ and $I$ do indeed match and that my closed formula for $J$ is correct. My question is:

- How can one go from the first equation to the integral set up in $J$? The notes I found say ***Use the reflection principle and the Strong Markov property to justify the identity***
- Is there a way to solve the integral $I$ directly? If so, how?

References:

- First hitting time density can be viewed here: [Density of first hitting time of Brownian motion with drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift)
- Expected value of an exponential brownian motion here: [Mean of exponential Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587703/mean-of-exponential-brownian-motion)
- Notes that I was reading, bottom of page 8(Careful -- lots of typos!): [https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/390/Lecture8.pdf](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/390/Lecture8.pdf) Note that their $\theta$ is equal to $-c$ in my notation.
- Numerical integration:
  [numerical integrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf19y.png)

Answer (score 2):

For the general case, I have not been able to establish the antiderivative required for computing $I$ which I rewrite
$$I=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp\Bigg[c \left(a+\frac{c T}{2}\right)\Bigg]\int_0^T t^{-\frac 32}\exp\Big[-\frac{a^2}{2 t}-\frac{c^2 t}{2}\Big]\,dt$$ For $J$
$$J=\frac 12 e^{a c}\exp\Big[\frac{c^2 T^2}{2}\Big]\Bigg[e^{-a c} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{a-c T}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{T}}\right)+e^{a c}
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{a+c T}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{T}}\right) \Bigg]$$

Suppose $c=0$; for such a case, we have
$$I=\frac 1 a \text{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2T} }\right)  \qquad \text{while} \qquad J=\text{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2T} }\right) $$ Computing for various general cases, what it seems is that
$$I =\frac J a $$ I supect (please confirm or negate) that your calculations have been done for $a=1$.